# Unexpected Indentation in Python interpreter

Tags: python, elpy

I am getting an indentation error in the Python interpreter while using elpy:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 3):
...     print(i)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(i)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I have tried with manually typing 4 spaces to ensure it wasn't the tab key. It seems as if the interpreter is getting some extra whitespace from the buffer but I am not sure. What could be causing this?

Comment: Well, turns out there is [a bug filed for this](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23678). Disabling company-mode and not triggering the built-in auto complete seems to fix it for me.